# react-leaflet curly braces on left top of the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

When the map is too far I can the curly braces and symbols near zoom pane. How can I get rid of them?

[image: react-leaflet bug]

p.s. provided some code

p.s. 2 - when I add a condition like 
    {condition1 && condition2 && it shows me brackets and zeros. How can I avoid it with leaving conditions?

```
return (

    <LeafMap
        preferCanvas={true}
        ref={mapRef}
        zoom={zoom}
        center={[deviceCoordinatesLat, deviceCoordinatesLong]}>
        <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                   attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"/>

        {condition1 && condition2 &&
        <Control position="topright">
            <div className="notification-circle">
                <img src={notificationRedCircle}/>
                <p>{countOfCondition2}</p>
            </div>
        </Control>}

        {markers.map(item => (
            <Marker
                className={item.id}
                key={item.id}
                position={[item.coordinates[0], item.coordinates[1]]}
                icon={
                    new L.Icon({
                        iconUrl: require('../../../frontend/src/images/map/1.png'),
                        iconSize: new L.Point(15, 15),
                    })
                }
            >
            </Marker>
        ))}
    </LeafMap>
)
};

export default Map
```

Comment: Can you show your code - as these are going to be coming from it

Comment: @developer there is nothing about it, sure. I can see those braces only when tiles are not loaded yet - while zooming and when I zoomed to the minimum - there is no tile so I can see this

Comment: This may come from another component in the page, do you got any other component there?

Comment: @SMAKSS you are right. It it the condition I use, got no idea how can I use it properly...

Comment: @deathfry One of the possible approaches to avoid this is to evaluate the condition outside the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

It is such an odd problem you have but it may lie under using multiple `{` and `}` nested. So one of the possible approaches to fix this is to evaluate your condition outside the JSX and then put a single value inside it.

So give this a shot:

```js
const conditionEval = condition1 && condition2;

return(
  ...
  {conditionEval &&
    <Control position="topright">
        <div className="notification-circle">
            <img src={notificationRedCircle}/>
            <p>{countOfCondition2}</p>
        </div>
    </Control>
  }
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SMAKSS I started to re-check all my code and found: 
- my condition was not evaluated to boolean - that's why there was 0
- I typed one redundant bracket in my code

Thanks all for effort!